# How to calculate covariance from variance?

Tags: covariance, variance

I have very little data to solve this question. How do I calculate market variance and covariance without the expected returns?

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGWIg.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Let $P=(A+B+C)/3$.  To calculate the covariance between $P$ and $A$, just use its linearity: $$\sigma_{PA}=(\sigma_{AA}+\sigma_{AB}+\sigma_{AC})/3.$$